# how to highlight the data based on index values in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I have the timeseries data, I want to highlight the portion of the `each` timeseries by using index values.
`For the first timeseries i want to highlight the portion from 35 to 55` 
`For the second timeseries i want to highlight the portion from 58 to 78`
#here dist is offset distsnace
The index values should be read from list `indx`

My code is here

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 9.5))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.06, 0.4, 0.28, 0.30])
indx=[45,68]
for idx,data in enumerate(data_stream):
    data= np.array(data))
    dist = data.dist
    ax1.plot(data + dist,np.arange(len(data)), lw=0.35, color='black')
    ax1.axhspan(indx-10, indx+10,xmin=0.15,xmax=0.4,color='red', alpha=0.1)
```

However, in my code the first timeseries only highlighted both by 35-55 and 58-78 index values and second timeseries doesnot get highlighted.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you confident on the ordering? Is it possible that the 2nd time series is receiving both?

Comment: no second timeseries doesnor receiving both...only first one receiving both

Comment: when i put ax1.axhspan(indx-10, indx+10,xmin=0.15,xmax=0.4,color='red', alpha=0.1) line outside the loop at that time the first timeseries highlighted with second indexed values(58:78)

Comment: Could you provide a sample set of data and a plot? I'm having some difficulty pinpointing exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @K.Cl how to upload data i donot know...can you please suggest some links to upload data

Comment: @K.Cl actually i want to shade the portion of timeseries based on given index values, however i have many time series so i want to adopt loop over it. while plotting using loop the first timeseries only shaded with different index ranges it is not shifting to the second timeseries

Comment: You can use google sheets and share a link, use pastebin and paste the csv if you're loading from it, or if the dataframe is small, you can paste it in the question.