# shading the area between two vertical lines with transparent color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to shade the area between the two vertical lines over the plot generated by below code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data=range(20)
ax.plot(data)
ax.plot(2.5,2.5, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(5.0,5.0, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)


plt.show()
```

I see `axvspan` but i am unable to solve,hope experts may help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know specifically what you want, as your description is a bit vague (it's always helpful to draw what you want in something like Inkscape, powerpoint or even paint when asking questions about graphs), so here's some possible solutions. First, using  [`ax.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_alpha.html).

Here's how to add a bar between your two indicated values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data=range(20)
ax.plot(data)
ax.plot(2.5,2.5, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(5.0,5.0, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)

ax.fill_between([2.5, 5.0], data[0], data[-1], alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image]

Maybe you want so modify the region a bit, create a smaller square. Modify the `fill_between` command to this:

```py
ax.fill_between([2.5, 5.0], 2.5, 5.0, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Perhaps you want something more like a "confidence interval". Then you'll need to modify your code a bit. Here's an example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data=np.arange(0, 20.5, step=0.5)
ax.plot(data, data)
ax.plot(2.5,2.5, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(5.0,5.0, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)

ax.fill_between(data, data-1, data+1, alpha=0.5, where=(data >= 2.5) & (data <= 5.0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: Now I saw you mentioned `axvspan`. It's very similar to `fill_between`. If you replace `fill_between` in the first example with this:

```py
ax.axvspan(2.5, 5.0, ymin=0, ymax=17, alpha=0.5)
```

You get this:

[image]

Comment: if my values are ax.plot(2.5,8.0, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(2.5,9.0, marker="|",color='blue',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.5,ms=10,alpha=0.5)    then what to set in fill_between

Comment: The first value is the left edge, second value is right edge. From your snippets, you have the points (2.5, 8.0) and (2.5, 9.0). These have the same x, but different y. This requires `fill_betweenx` or `axhfill`. Use these commands: `ax.fill_betweenx([8, 9], data[0], data[-1], alpha=0.5)` or `ax.axhspan(8, 9, xmin=data[0], xmax=data[-1], alpha=0.5)`

Comment: Thanks @ K.Cl for your answer, if you donot mind can you please have a look into  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928342/how-to-highlight-the-data-based-on-index-values-in-loop

Comment: if i have many lines and i want to shade with different index values how can it be solved

Comment: Just add more commands to each region you want shaded. Ideally, draw what you want manually and then we can go directly to the point.